# Possibility to get titles or urls of webpages in Firefox tabs from command line?

Tags: bash, firefox

As root on a machine, from the command line. Is it possible to get the titles (or urls) of the webpages opened by a user in Firefox tabs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, You have to navigate to Firefox/profiles/session/{random-string}-default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4

That file holds the current tabs compressed in LZ4 format. you can use cat to get a gist of whats in there but you'll have to decompress it using either python or https://github.com/andikleen/lz4json

There's a more in depth answer with a python script here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/385023/firefox-reading-out-urls-of-opened-tabs-from-the-command-line

You might have to hack it up a bit given that its 4 years old however the file structure of Firefox seems to have remained almost the same.

Note, you'll have to find the specifics of where each operating system sets the files e.g for mac osx it's in /users/$USER/Library/Application\ Support/Firefox/Profiles/{random-string}-default/sessionstore-backups/recovery.jsonlz4

I'm not exactly sure where other operating systems hold it